# jQuery split cell into multiple rows

Tags: jquery

I would like to split a table with a single tr and the cells must be split into half into the next row.

Example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>
     1 Content content Content content Content content Content content
     2 Content content Content content Content content Content content
     3 Content content Content content Content content Content content
     4 Content content Content content Content content Content content
   </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Results into:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>
     1 Content content Content content Content content Content content
     2 Content content Content content Content content Content content
   </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
     3 Content content Content content Content content Content content
     4 Content content Content content Content content Content content
   </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

And if its multiple td's it will make rows with multi td's all split in half

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+split+table+cell+content+into+rows+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Split on what? Newlines?

Comment: *And if its multiple td's it will make rows with multi td's all split in half* - recursive?  So you end up with 4 `tr` each with one `td`/line from your starting example?

Comment: If it is multiple td then they wil have the same amount of td. in the next row.

Answer (score 0):

Given the minimal information I have, you can try this

```js
const tableCells = document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr td")
tableCells.forEach(cell => {
  const content = cell.textContent.trim().split(/\r?\n/);
  if (content.length > 1) {
    cell.textContent = content.slice(0,content.length/2).join('\n')
    const newRow = document.createElement('tr')
    newRow.innerHTML = `<td>${content.slice(content.length/2).join('\n')}</td>`
    const parentRow = cell.closest('tr');
    parentRow.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, parentRow.nextSibling);
  }
  
})
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
1 Content content Content content Content content Content content
2 Content content Content content Content content Content content
3 Content content Content content Content content Content content
4 Content content Content content Content content Content content
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
1 Content content Content content Content content Content content
2 Content content Content content Content content Content content
3 Content content Content content Content content Content content
4 Content content Content content Content content Content content
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```